# require_once: failed to open stream: Permission denied(lampp)

Tags: permissions, php, lamp

I need help solving , what says to be a permission error in the `htdocs` folder, because i needed to alter them to even add folders in the first place.

This is my `init.php` file:

```
<?php
//Start Session
session_start();

//Include Configuration
require_once('config/config.php');

//Helper Function Files
require_once('helpers/system_helper.php');
require_once('helpers/format_helper.php');
require_once('helpers/db_helper.php');

//Autoload Classes
function __autoload($class_name){
require_once('libraries/'.$class_name . '.php');
}
?>
```

I try to include it via `

When i run my `index.php` file i get this error:

```
Warning: require_once(../../htdocs/PHP-Wizard/helpers/system_helper.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../htdocs/PHP-Wizard/helpers/system_helper.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 9
```

I tried going one folder up with `../` , but it doesn't work.

I looked around for a similar error to mine, but no luck. They all say `No such file or directory in (path)`.

Could it be that it is the same error, or do i really need to change my permissions, if so, how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had similar problem. This was what I did:

1. `chmod` my files to 755. You can do this by using (you can try `chmod`ing all files and dirs :p ) but please try step 2 first:

   ```
   chmod -R 755 your_folder/
   ```
2. Since my classes name began with a small letter which is incorrect

   look for this line in your init file:

   ```
   require_once('libraries/'.$class_name . '.php');
   ```

   and replace with

   ```
   require_once 'classes/' . strtolower($class) . '.php';
   ```

This got it working for me. I hope I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

or you can **fix** it **manually** 
just simply go to that **directory** where

```
(../../htdocs/PHP-Wizard/helpers/system_helper.php)
```

and **right click** over there and go to permission and change from **read only** to **create & delete** .

hence problem solved (as i was also sufferd from the same problem this is how i fix them) 
;-)